# ErrorException thrown with message "Trying to get property 'user' of non-object

Tags: laravel

I am using relationship in my laravel project. I am trying to show my post and replies. But i keep getting this error. I've tried various solution but none of them worked. Can anyone help me?

Post model:

```
protected $fillable = [
                'title', 'content', 'category_id' , 'slug', 'user_id',
            ];
public function user1()
        {
                return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
        }
public function replies()
        {
                return $this->hasMany('App\Reply');
        }
```

Reply model:

```
  protected $fillable = ['content','user_id','posts_id'];


    public function post(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

PostController:

```
public function shro($slug)
    {
        $pst= Post::where('slug',$slug)->first();
        return view('posts.show')->with('p', $pst);
    }
```

show.blade.php

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">

    <img src="/uploads/avatars/{{ $p->user->avatar }}" alt="" width="70px" height="60px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span>{{ $p->user->name }}, <b>{{ $p->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</b></span></br>


    </div>
```

Comment: change the line where you return the view to `return view('posts.show')->with('pst');` and adapt your view to `{{ $pst->user->name }}`

Comment: You can also change it to `return view('posts.show', ['p' => $pst]);` to keep the name `p` of the variable

Comment: doesn't work. still shows ''''Trying to get property 'user' of non-object'''

Comment: @N69S Good advice, but not the issue here. That return using `->with()` is fine (albeit confusing)

Answer (score 0):

`$p`, or `$pst` (confusing variable names) is `null`, and this is because `->first()` can return `null`. Do you have a `Post` record in your database that matched `slug`?

Rule of thumb; **never assume something exists**.

Add some logic to ensure the `Post` exists before trying to access a property of it:

```
$post = Post::where("slug", $slug)->first();
if(!$post){
  abort(404);
}
return view('posts.show')->with('post', $post);

// OR

$post = Post::where("slug", $slug)->findOrFail(); // or firstOrFail();
return view('posts.show')->with('post', $post);
```

Also, check your `$post->user`:

```
@if($post->user)
<img src="/uploads/avatars/{{ $post->user->avatar }}" width="70px" height="60px"/>
<span>{{ $post->user->name }}, <b>{{ $post->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</b></span></br>
@endif
```

If `$post->user` returns `null`, you'll have a similar error.

Comment: I did exactly what you did..Now creating post page is not found. and I can not access the post that were in the database which was showing earlier. i am bit of a confused :/

Comment: I have exactly same another home page which is showing all the posts. That was working till now. but i the option to create a new post is gone and saying the error i posted. In the home page i used foreach and it worked fine.

Comment: Hmm, not sure about all of that. This should have solved/alleviated the immediate issue, but if there's more to your question, you have a couple options; add more information to your question, or close this one and ask a new, more focused question.

Answer (score 0):

You can eager load the user with it's relative post at once by doing :

```
    //...
    $pst= Post::where('slug',$slug)->with(['user1'])->first();
    //...
```